# Do Animal Crossing: New Horizon's wetsuits wear out?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I noticed the wetsuits are with the tools in Nook's Cranny. Does this mean like tools, they wear out? If they do, can I craft new ones or do I have to buy them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't wear out. You can't craft them yourself, but there are different variations in Nook's Cranny, Nook Shopping and Nook Stop.

Comment: Compare to the infinite-durability Ladder and Vaulting Pole -- also tools!